# How do I elegantly retrieve and delete an item from a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I would like to return an item using its key *and* delete it at the same time. Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

**Inelegant Solution**

```
const popItem = (key) => {
  const popped = items[key]
  delete items[key]
  return popped
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this discussion. I think you need to stay inelegant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
const items = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
const popItem = (obj, key) => [obj[key], delete obj[key]][0];

console.log(popItem(items, 2));  // 'two'
console.log(items);              // { 1: 'one; }
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/tosupayune/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Or if you want to return the new obj from the function as well:

```
const items = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
const popItem = (obj, key) => [obj[key], [delete obj[key], obj][1]];
const [newObj, item] = popItem(items, 1);

console.log(newObj)  // 'one'
console.log(item)    // { 2: "two" }
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/jepurejuqo/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: An elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try not to mutate it?

```
const popItem = (obj, key) => {
 { [key], ...rest } = obj;
 return { popped: key, newObj: rest };
};
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
const { popped, newObj } = popItem(obj, key);
```